# Trouble installing ODBC Driver 11 on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: php, iis, sql-server-2012, odbc, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm trying to install a php application (TestRail) on a Windows Server 2012 R2 VM and am having some trouble with SQL drivers. I started off by installing SQL Server 2012 from disc and attempting to install PHP from the Web Platform Installer, although the download for Microsoft Drivers 3.2 for PHP v5.6 for SQL Server in IIS kept failing, citing a missing dependency as the culprit. Looking through the log, I seee:

```
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Moving downloaded file 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\2\tmpC703.tmp' to: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\MSODBC11\08A089BA4D1F22BB46A4553E20095A271C230D2E\msodbcsql.msi
DownloadManager Error: 0 : Signature verification failed on downloaded file. URL: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=533081. File location: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\MSODBC11\08A089BA4D1F22BB46A4553E20095A271C230D2E\msodbcsql.msi. File size: 3768 kb
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product Microsoft® ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server® done install completed
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Increasing current install to 2
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Dependency failed for product 'Microsoft Drivers 3.2 for PHP v5.6 for SQL Server in IIS'. Skipping download.
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product Microsoft Drivers 3.2 for PHP v5.6 for SQL Server in IIS had a dependency fail. Increasing install product to 3
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product: MSODBC11, Install Status: InstallCompleted-Failure, Install Time: 00:00:00
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product: SQLDriverPHP56IIS, Install Status: DependencyFailed-None, Install Time: 00:00:00
```

It looked like the dependency is the ODBC Driver 11, which wouldn't install due to signature verification, so I decided to just grab everything manually. I got the 3.2 php drivers and put them in the ext directory and registered them in php.ini and all that, but when I tried to run the msodbcsql.msi package that was giving me issues with the Web Platform Installer I kept getting an error that installation failed because it is unsupported on my operating system. However, the download page on Microsoft's site lists Server 2012 as compatible, and when I run sqlsrv_errors() I get:

```
[message] => This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 )
```

and

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified ) )
```

So it looks like it's still looking for that ODBC driver, but when I try to download it from the link specified in the error message it tells me that it's incompatible with my OS and when I try to use WPI it fails signature verification. The only other post here I've seen recommends grabbing the x64 version instead of the x86 version, but this is not an option on the page and it seems weird that the Web Platform Installer would even attempt to install an incompatible driver. How can I get this driver installed?

Comment: Did you install `1033\amd64\msodbcsql.msi` from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434

Comment: Well dang. I assumed that would only work for AMD architecture since most of the other downloads specify x64... what an easy fix for something I was going nuts over! Thanks : )

Comment: Yes...there's a whole history behind why it's called AMD64, even on Intel 64 bit processors: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64

Comment: Having the exact same issue. I installed the msodbcsql.msi manually but when I try to install the php drivers through WPI it just downloads the odbc again which still fails signature verification.

Comment: I never got WPI to work for me, but installing everything manually worked. Since msodbcsql is all set, it seems like you just need to install the PHP drivers manually from [https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098). Download the one that matches your installed version of php as detailed under the system requrements, copy the dlls for your version (probably the nts ones) to php/ext, and load them into php.ini.

Comment: Thanks, that was easy enough!

Answer (score 0):

Hey get Updated ODBC driver from: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434